# is there any way to validate XQuery through regular expression?

Tags: objective-c, regex, xquery

is there any way to validate XQuery through regular expression?

i want to use that in my objective c program.

Comment: In general: no. Regular expression are generally not an appropriate tool for this job. However, perhaps they could be used in *your specific case*, which should be talked about in the post.

Answer (score 2):

The [XQuery Grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#nt-bnf) was noted in E-BNF. [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) is a notation for context-free grammars, which are less restricted than regular grammatics (which are eg. described by regular expressions). Generally, there is no way to transform grammars to languages *lower* on the [Chomsky Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).

Lots of theoretical computer sciences, and nobody tells us for sure the XQuery working group didn't just use BNF for convenience and could have used REGEX to describe the grammar.

But let's have another point of view. XQuery allows to load arbitrary code from other modules. If the implementation allows this, even HTTP ressources are allowed, eg. `import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xq";` (don't do this in your application, mirror the functx library - loading from a web page will be much slower and functx guys won't like you). So you need to parse (at least some parts) of your XQuery to even get all code.

---

Choose some XQuery implementation and use it. There are [lots around](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/#implementations), Apple even includes one in [NSXML](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/QueryingXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001258-CJBFCGEG).

Answer (score 0):

No, a context-free language which isn't a regular language cannot be recognized with a regular expression.

More specifically, a CF language needs an unlimited memory structure (like a stack) in order to be parsed, which is not the case with regular language recognition, where a fixed amount of memory only is needed (for a finite automaton).

XQuery is in fact a language with quite complicated grammar. It contains the whole XPath 2.0 language as a subset. In the past I have produced a parser for XPath 2.0 and know its grammar. It has around 210 rules. This itself speaks about the complexity of XPath 2.0 and XPath 2.0 is just a subset of XQuery.